# Jupyter Notebook not connecting to kernel

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I was running the jupyter notebook in a virtual enviroment using `jupyter notebook`.
Everything seemed normal until it tries to connect to the kernel where it shows `A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.`. Firefox Console shows this:

```
WebSocket closed unexpectedly close { target: WebSocket, isTrusted: true, wasClean: false, code: 1006, reason: "", srcElement: WebSocket, currentTarget: WebSocket, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, … }
GETws://localhost:8888/api/kernels/7fefd4d5-1171-41fa-a26a-eb5983a3dbd7/channels?session_id=7ed74089d4dc46bc8a7324437e65a69c
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 3ms]

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8888/api/kernels/7fefd4d5-1171-41fa-a26a-eb5983a3dbd7/channels?session_id=7ed74089d4dc46bc8a7324437e65a69c. kernel.js:466
Kernel: kernel_disconnected (7fefd4d5-1171-41fa-a26a-eb5983a3dbd7) kernel.js:107
WebSocket connection failed:  ws://localhost:8888/api/kernels/7fefd4d5-1171-41fa-a26a-eb5983a3dbd7 true kernel.js:547
Failed to reconnect, giving up. kernel.js:572
WebSocket closed unexpectedly 
close { target: WebSocket, isTrusted: true, wasClean: false, code: 1006, reason: "", srcElement: WebSocket, currentTarget: WebSocket, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, … }
kernel.js:494
```

My terminal window throws this error:

```
[I 05:36:25.780 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 3d141e13-48cc-4ec2-8ce4-278d7d3813a2, name: venv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/nithi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/home/nithi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .connect import *  # noqa
  File "/home/nithi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 11, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "/home/nithi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_client/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .asynchronous import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa
  File "/home/nithi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_client/asynchronous/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa
  File "/home/nithi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_client/asynchronous/client.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ..client import KernelClient, reqrep
  File "/home/nithi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_client/client.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .connect import ConnectionFileMixin
  File "/home/nithi/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 14, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tempfile.py", line 184, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
ImportError: cannot import name 'Random' from 'random' (/home/nithi/random.py)
```

Anyone got any idea why this is happening?